# RGBDSLAM - Slow transform pub‏lishing

Tags: ros, tf-listener, tf-broadcaster, rgbdslam-v2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have the RGBD SLAM v2 package (http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/) running on a Core i7 computer with a Nvidia GTX 780 graphics card. The computer runs Ubuntu 12.04.5 and ROS Hydro.

I want to use the package for robot localization, but it seems like I'm getting a too low pub rate of the transform.

In my launch file I have:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_local_origin" output="screen" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /local_origin 10" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="mav_to_camera" output="screen" args="-0.05 0.15 0.8 0 1.570796 0 vision camera_link 10" />
```

which are transforms that I need to exist for sending the pose estimation for the robot. I also have:

```
 <!-- TF information settings -->
    <param name="config/fixed_frame_name"              value="/map"/>
    <param name="config/ground_truth_frame_name"       value=""/><!--empty string if no ground truth-->
    <param name="config/base_frame_name"               value="vision"/> <!-- /openni_camera for hand-held kinect. For robot, e.g., /base_link -->
    <param name="config/fixed_camera"                  value="false"/> <!--is the kinect fixed with respect to base, or can it be moved (false makes sense only if transform betw. base_frame and openni_camera is sent via tf)-->
```

where 'vision' is considered the base of the robot. 'till now everything is ok. The problem comes when I run the package and start processing. Using the tf view_frames, I can check the following on the tf tree:

```
Broadcaster: /rgbdslam
Average rate: 10000.000 Hz
Most recent transform: 1409946186.276
Buffer length: 0.000 sec
```

which for sure is not right, given that as said in http://answers.ros.org/question/54240/using-robot_pose_ekf-and-rgbdslam-for-path-planning-with-octomaps/?answer=54312#post-id-54312 the tf transform is being sent at a 10Hz rate supposedly, which I know it can be less, but less can't be what is in the following: (Issuing 'rosrun tf tf_monitor')

```
Node: /rgbdslam 0.202653 Hz, Average Delay: 1.97535 Max Delay: 11.3705
```

Which is extremely slow! Does someone has a tip for what is happening or why is it so slow?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192463/rgbdslam---slow-transform-pub%E2%80%8Flishing/) by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 210 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [msandertar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22386/msandertar/) on 2015-05-09**:
Hi, I have the same problem, using ros indigo dist. Some tf pubs seems to have 10000 HZ frecuency although I publish them at 10 HZ.
Could you solve your problem? How did you solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Statistics on static transforms may be a problem. I don't think the statistics calculations have been updated since static transforms were introduce. Static transforms are published only once on a latched topics and republish only on change, but they are always queryable. Thus depending on the detection method they may report very slow or very fast.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0